# Getting JavaScript data from MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using the timeline option from google Charts to display some item availability.

Link: [Google Chart Timeline](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)

it displays something like the following

[image]

with the this code:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'President',          'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    [ 'President',          'John Adams',        new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    [ 'President',          'Thomas Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Vice President',     'John Adams',        new Date(1789, 3, 20), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Vice President',     'Thomas Jefferson',  new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Vice President',     'Aaron Burr',        new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1805, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Vice President',     'George Clinton',    new Date(1805, 2, 3),  new Date(1812, 3, 19)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Jay',          new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 21)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'Thomas Jefferson',  new Date(1790, 2, 21), new Date(1793, 11, 30)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'Edmund Randolph',   new Date(1794, 0, 1),  new Date(1795, 7, 19)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'Timothy Pickering', new Date(1795, 7, 19), new Date(1800, 4, 11)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'Charles Lee',       new Date(1800, 4, 12), new Date(1800, 5, 4)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'John Marshall',     new Date(1800, 5, 12), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'Levi Lincoln',      new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 4, 0)],
    [ 'Secretary of State', 'James Madison',     new Date(1801, 4, 1),  new Date(1809, 2, 2)]]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

I would like a variable number of the names of the columns (dataTable.addColumn) to come from an MVC controller. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want to add n number of columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as this script is in the view, not in a JS file, you can inject variables in like:

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: '@Model.FirstColumnName' });
```

MVC allows you to do a lot that gets injected into the script; remember it's server-side code getting rendered to client-side markup.  You just have to make sure it gets rendered correctly.  I even had utilities that converted models into JSON objects in my view, without issue.

Comment: What if we wanted to use unobtrusive JavaScript? any way beside using ajax call?

Comment: My approach didn't use AJAX, it was using server side rendering inside client markup.

Comment: I know, what I meant was passing data to separate .js file.

Comment: Oh OK, well, not necessarily AJAX, but it adds complexity.  What you can do is build up a JSON "configuration" object with the configuration from the model, and pass that JSON object to a method in your JS file, which then is used to supply the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a MVC controller method that returns a JSON object that has the `type` and `id` properties and do an ajax call to retrieve them

```
$.getJSON( "/Columns", function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      //use dataTable.addColumn to add columns
    });
});
```